# FreeBSDでOpenCVが導入できない

Tags: opencv, freebsd

FreeBSDでOpenCVを用いたサンプルをコンパイルしたいのですが、パッケージが存在しないとエラーが出てしまいます。FreeBSD上でOpenCVをインストールした結果は以下のとおりです。

```
# make install
===>  Installing for opencv-3.4.1_4
===>  Checking if opencv already installed
===>   Registering installation for opencv-3.4.1_4
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_annotation - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_createsamples - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_interactive-calibration - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_traincascade - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_version - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_version - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_visualisation - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_waldboost_detector - required shared library libopencv_imgproc.so.3.4 not found
(opencv-3.4.1_4) /usr/ports/graphics/opencv/work/stage//usr/local/bin/opencv_waldboost_detector - required shared library libopencv_core.so.3.4 not found
Installing opencv-3.4.1_4...
===>   NOTICE:

The opencv port currently does not have a maintainer. As a result, it is
more likely to have unresolved issues, not be up-to-date, or even be removed in
the future. To volunteer to maintain this port, please create an issue at:

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla

More information about port maintainership is available at:

https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/contributing/ports-contributing.html#maintain-port
```

ソースコード

```java
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class Hello{

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    String input = "/home/○○/lena.jpg";
    String output = "/home/○○/opencvsample/result.jpg";
    //Mat matrixSrc = new Mat();
    //Mat matrixDst = new Mat();

    // 入力画像の読み込み
    //matrixSrc = Imgcodecs.imread(input);
    // カラー画像をグレー画像に変換
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(matrixSrc, matrixDst, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    //Imgcodecs.imwrite(output, matrixDst);

    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

どうすればOpenCVを用いたソースがコンパイルできるか分かる人回答お願いします。
エラーメッセージ

```
javac -classpath /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-341.jar Hello.java
java -cp /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-341.jar Hello
エラー: メイン・クラスHelloが見つからなかったかロードできませんでした
java -cp /usr/local/share/OpenCV/java/opencv-341.jar:/home/○○/opencvsample Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java341 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
    at Hello.main(Hello.java:9)
```

Comment: マルチポスト - https://teratail.com/questions/145264

Comment: 先に graphics/opencv-core をインストールしてみては?

Comment: OpenCV-coreをインストールしても結果は同じでした。

Comment: エラーを見た感じではOpenCV関係なく、main関数が呼び出せてないだけな気がします。OpenCVに関するコードをコメントアウトしても同じエラーが出ませんか？例えば最後のDoneを出力しているコードだけにしてみるとか。

Comment: 最後のDoneを出力するだけのソースになるようにコメントアウトしてみたところ、Doneは出力されました。

Comment: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError が発生していますので、OpenCV 関連の共有ライブラリ(shared library)のロードに失敗しているのではないかと思います。[How to Load a Java Native/Shared Library (.so) by calling System.loadLibrary or System.load](https://www.chilkatsoft.com/java-loadLibrary-Linux.asp) が参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。System.loadを使ってlibopencv_java.soにパスを通して上手くいきました。